# How to change the width of columns in a pricing table

Tags: wordpress

i just started to create a [website](http://berlinautoreinigung.de/autoreinigung/innenreinigung/) for the carwash of my dad. i am new in this field and getting stuck in the following issue.

So i bought the avada template and insert the price table. 
How can i reduce the width of the columns including the price?

and in which programming language are the shortcodes written in wordpress?
e.g. this one:

```
[pricing_table type="1" backgroundcolor="#a6c3dd" bordercolor="" dividercolor="" class="" id=""]
[pricing_column title='Standardpflege' standout="yes"]
[pricing_row]Vorwäsche[/pricing_row]
[pricing_row]Außenreinigung[/pricing_row]
[pricing_row]Reifen-Felgenreinigung[/pricing_row]
[pricing_row]Reifen-Felgenreinigung[/pricing_row]
[/pricing_column]
[pricing_column title='Kleinwagen'][pricing_price currency='€' price='15.55' ][/pricing_price][/pricing_column]
[pricing_column title='Mittelklasse'][pricing_price currency='€' price='15.55' ][/pricing_price][/pricing_column]
[pricing_column title='Oberklasse'][pricing_price currency='€' price='15.55' ][/pricing_price][/pricing_column]
[/pricing_table]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom CSS plugin you can add something like :

```
#wrapper .full-boxed-pricing .panel-wrapper {
    width: 15%;
}
```